The system cannot find the file specified typescript
I'm trying to run build containers in docker but im getting an error The system cannot find the file specified

Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230 
Docker Desktop 4.35.1 (173168)
Windows 11 Pro version 23H2

the error is happening when I run
docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
You can see folder structure in the image, I want to mention something that I'm finding it strange when I run the command why it ends with you-app-backend ?
resolve : CreateFile C:\Users\user\Desktop\YOUAPP_FULLSTACK_PROJECT\you-app-backend\notification-microservice\you-app-backend:
Shouldn't be notification-microservice only? In addition, why every time when I run the command the path is changing to another microservice?

docker compose
services:
  youapp-frontend-container:
    build:
      context: ./you-app-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: youapp-frontend-container
    ports:
      - "5300:5300"
    volumes:
      - ./you-app-frontend:/youapp_fullstack_project
      - /youapp_fullstack_project/node_modules
    env_file:
      - ./you-app-frontend/.env
    depends_on:
      - api-gateway-container

  api-gateway-container:
    build:
      context: ./you-app-backend
      dockerfile: api-gateway/Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: api-gateway-container
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./you-app-backend/api-gateway:/youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/api-gateway
      - /youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/api-gateway/node_modules
      - ./you-app-backend/shared:/youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/shared
    env_file:
      - ./you-app-backend/api-gateway/.env
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5673
    depends_on:
      - auth-microservice
      - mongo

  auth-microservice:
    build:
      context: ./you-app-backend
      dockerfile: auth-microservice/Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: auth-microservice
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
    volumes:
      - ./you-app-backend/auth-microservice:/youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/auth-microservice
      # - /youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/auth-microservice/node_modules
      - ./you-app-backend/shared:/youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/shared
    env_file:
      - ./you-app-backend/auth-microservice/.env
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  user-microservice:
    build:
      context: ./you-app-backend
      dockerfile: user-microservice/Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: user-microservice
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    volumes:
      - ./you-app-backend/user-microservice:/youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/user-microservice
      # - /youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/user-microservice/node_modules
      - ./you-app-backend/shared:/youapp_fullstack_project/you-app-backend/shared
    env_file:
      - ./you-app-backend/user-microservice/.env
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: on-failure:5
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    ports:
      - "5673:5672"
      - "15673:15672"
    restart: on-failure:5

volumes:
  mongo-data:



Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; more specifically, what is in your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml?  Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  If some of the information is in the image file you've attached, please replace it with plain text.

i added compose docker file and my problem has been solved , for that reason i cant add the error as plain text but generally i wont upload an image again , thank u

Your issue is related to the dockerfile paths provided for the microservice containers. You're already passing in a context and dockerfile is relative to context as mentioned in the docs.
Replace each dockerfile in the docker-compose.dev.yml file to Dockerfile.dev, for example:
  chat-service:
    build:
      context: ./you-app-backend/chat-microservice
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: chat-microservice


can i ask u another question if u dont mind?

Go ahead no problem, though if it's unrelated you might benefit from creating a new post altogether.

no it's related but the problem is stackoverflow found that my question needs to be better and i'm not able to create new post for that reason ...  :(  before telling u about my question i appreciate if u can add one to my question so maybe that can help ...  now the main problem is when im working with docker i read some articles say that i cant use localhost as host name and i should use service name instead... i dont actually i tried but i'm getting an error when i make a request to login something related to host in docker i think... i dont if u can fork or clone my application and see it

As a little suggestion for the future, your question should be clear and should not depend on details found on other sites. The reason for this is that your question might not be easily searchable or if you decide to take down your repo the question will no longer have any code to support it. So you should include your docker compose in the question directly and the errors should also be text instead of an image.

Now, to answer your question, the reason why localhost doesn't work inside docker is because containers typically run inside a virtual network. This means that each container works as separate machine and each of them have different IPs. To then localhost is the loopback to the container and not your host. The solution should be update your code so that the URLs to consume each microservice be defined as environment variables and pass them from the docker-compose file. The IP of each container would be the name of the container instead of localhost. Does this make sense?

does this work without needing to add anything else like defining networks or anything else in docker compose ? so for example you telling me like to edit host name here from '127.0.0.1' to auth container name ? imports: [ ClientsModule.registerAsync([ { inject: [ConfigService], name: 'AUTH_SERVICE', useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({ transport: Transport.TCP, options: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: configService.get('AUTH_SERVICE_PORT'), }, }), }, ]), ]

Yes. Let's say you use that code to connect to the auth service. If you auth service is available in the auth container, replace the host with auth. By default l, docker compose stacks define their own network unless you specify otherwise. Though for portability reasons you should pass those variables as environment variables instead of hardcoding them on your project.
